# Java remote interactions

Tags: java, operating-system, remote-server, interaction

I'm in internship, and my mission is to build a deployment program in Java. My approach was based on a "tasks to do for a deployment" model with dynamic instanciation (but this is not the point). Every task does something locally or on the remote server (sometimes both). For example, I have a `Copy` task which copies a local file to the remote server. Got some tasks like this for basic interactions (Move, Delete, ...).

The point is, each deployment module is a server which has different parameters (OS, connection params, ...) and basic programs. One of them is a Linux server, so I figured I could use SSH (with [JSCh](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/)) to do the job. But the other is a Windows machine, with no SSH whatsoever. I searched everywhere for several days to find what could be used, with no results.

**So here is my question:**

what Java API should I use to get the job done?

Is it possible with Telnet or FTP?

Is it possible at all without ssh ?

**Little detail:** I don't have any control on remote servers, I can't install new protocols or programs, nor have a `RMI server` launched on them.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: I had same problem sometimes, but if you can't install a piece of software on the windows remote system you have to write different ways for different machines, For Windows e.g. the windows way ;-)

Comment: I forgot to say : I use dynamic instanciation for my tasks which allows me to specify a behaviour according to the server's operating system. So the "windows way for windows" and "linux way for linux" isn't a problem. The problem is : I don't have a way for windows ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few options to interact with a remote Windows server. If your local Java application is running on Windows (that is, both your source and target server are running Windows), you can spawn a new process and execute PowerShell commands - see [this link](http://technirman.blogspot.com/2014/06/invoke-powershell-commands-through-java.html) for an example.

There are ways to [copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10741609/copy-file-remotely-with-powershell) and [delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20667310/powershell-to-delete-desktop-items-from-a-remote-pc) files on a remote server using PowerShell. Since you didn't fully specify your requirements, I don't know if that covers all your use cases or not.

If your application does not run on Windows, you'll have to resort to a pure Java solution like [j-Interop](http://www.j-interop.org/) to connect to the remote system using DCOM / WMI. See [this page](https://nikunjp.wordpress.com/category/wmi/) for a good introduction to WMI and j-Interop. Word of warning though - getting DCOM to work requires some configuration changes, specifically changing permissions on registry keys, on modern versions of Windows (Windows 7 and up).

Comment: I'll take a look to j-Interop, thanks ! For the powershell solution, it can't be, unfortunately, my application is local, but I have to launch commands on a remote server. I'll try to beg them to install OpenSSH too.

Comment: My point was that power shell can execute remote commands, as long as both the local and the remote server run on Windows.